# How does having multiple DataContexts work?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I am building an application that has several tabs within the MainWindow view, each containing a couple DataGrids and varying bits of data. I've been researching all week on how to set the DataContext to multiple tables/objects/queries. The only answer I can seem to find from a couple different sources is to create a ViewModel container like so:

```
class VMContainer
{
    public ViewModel1 VM1 {get; set;}
    public ViewModel2 VM2 {get; set;}
}
```

However, I'm unable to find anything that further explains what this is doing. From my perspective, it doesn't seem like there's ever a point where the call for data is being made. Even further, I cannot fathom how to create a call that returns all of the datasets that I need into one object. Can anyone explain how this work or direct me to an article that explains having multiple sets of data as the datacontext of a view?

Edit : How do I return a dataset of datasets?

Thanks.

Comment: [What is the X Y problem, and how do I fix it?](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I guess the problem is I can't figure out how to return a dataset of many datasets. If that makes sense.

Comment: A tabcontrol is a subtype of itemscontrol. Create a viewmodel for the window. That has a public property which is a list or observablecoleection of object. Bind that to itemssource of the tabcontrol. Define a viewmodel class per tab. Define a usercontrol per tab. Associate each usercontrol with viewmodel as a datatemplate using datatype = viewmodel type. That last part is standard in viewmodel first and you should be able to google examples.

Answer (score 1):

With a tab control, normally you would see a separate view for each tab's content, and each view would have an accompanying view-model.

A view-model provides the view with the data/properties it needs to display via data binding.

A single view-model can provide many different sets of data. When you mention a dataset, most likely this would be represented in the view-model as a `ObservableCollection<T>` property.

Here's a simple example of one of those properties using an MVVM framework that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
private ObservableCollection<MyDataType> myDataSet1;
public ObservableCollection<MyDataType> MyDataSet1
{
    get => myDataSet1;
    set => SetProperty(ref myDataSet1, value);
}
```

A view-model can provide many of these properties to the view.

When the view-model is instantiated you would have code that would do the data access and get the data from the database, and you would expose it through your properties so that the view can data bind to them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had thought about breaking the tabs into different views/view-models but I wasn't sure whether that was the correct way to do it or not. I feel like it may slow the application down when navigating from tab to tab. Either way, I would still need to set the DataContext to multiple datasets for a majority of the tabs which is where I'm confused. I can't figure out what to set the datacontext to exactly.

Comment: You would set the DataContext of the view to its corresponding view-model. Also, if there is a lot of data shared across tabs, there's no rule that says you can't have a single view-model for the entire tab control.